# MysqlDataReader.Read stuck on the last record and doesnt EOF

Tags: vb.net, datareader, oledbdatareader, mysqldatareader

i confused why mySqlDataReader.Read stuck on the last record and doesnt EOF ..

Here's my private function for executeSql :

```
Private Function executeSQL(ByVal str As String, ByVal connString As String, ByVal returnRecordSet As Boolean) As Object
    Dim cmd As Object
    Dim objConn As Object
    Try
        If dbType = 2 Then
            cmd = New MySqlCommand
            objConn = New MySqlConnection(connString)
        Else
            cmd = New OleDbCommand
            objConn = New OleDbConnection(connString)
        End If
        'If objConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then objConn.Close()
        objConn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = objConn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = str
        If returnRecordSet Then
            executeSQL = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            executeSQL.Read()
        Else
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            executeSQL = Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description & " @ExecuteSQL", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "ExecuteSQL")
    End Try
End Function
```

And this is my sub to call it where the error occurs :

```
Using admsDB As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=" & rs("server") & ";uid=" & rs("user") & ";password=" & rs("pwd") & ";port=" & rs("port") & ";database=adms_db;")
                    admsDB.Open()
                    connDef.Close()
                    rs.Close()
                    'get record on admsdb
                    Dim logDate As DateTime
                    Dim str As String
                    str = "select userid, checktime from adms_db.checkinout in_out where userid not in (select userid " &
                        "from adms_db.checkinout in_out join (select str_to_date(datetime,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') tgl, fid from zsoft_bkd_padang.ta_log) ta " &
                        "on ta.fid=userid and tgl=checktime)"
                    Dim rsAdms As MySqlDataReader = executeSQL(str, admsDB.ConnectionString, True)
                    Dim i As Integer
                    'This is where the error is, datareader stuck on the last record and doesnt EOF
                    While rsAdms.HasRows
                        'i = i + 1 
                        logDate = rsAdms(1)
                        'save to ta_log
                        str = "insert into ta_log (fid, Tanggal_Log, jam_Log, Datetime) values ('" & rsAdms(0) & "','" & Format(logDate.Date, "dd/MM/yyyy") & "', '" & logDate.ToString("hh:mm:ss") & "', '" & logDate & "')"
                        executeSQL(str, oConn.ConnectionString, False)
                        rsAdms.Read()
                    End While

                    'del record on admsdb
                    str = "truncate table checkinout"
                    executeSQL(str, admsDB.ConnectionString, False)
                End Using
```

i'm new to vbnet and really have a little knowledge about it,, please help me,, and thank you in advance..

Comment: Do you get an actual error message?

Comment: there's no actual error message, it's just the loop doesnt end and stuck at the last record,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the `HasRows` property as your loop termination expression.  The value of that property never changes.  Either the reader has rows or it doesn't.  It's not a check of whether it has rows left to read, so reading has no effect.

You are supposed to use the `Read` method as your flag.  The data reader begins without a row loaded.  Each time you call `Read`, it will load the next row and return `True` or, if there are no more rows to read, it returns `False`.

You normally only use `HasRows` if you want to do something special when the result set is empty, e.g.

```
If myDataReader.HasRows Then
    '...
Else
    MessageBox.Show("No matches found")
End If
```

If you don't want to treat an empty result set as a special case then simply call `Read`:

```
While myDataReader.Read()
    Dim firstFieldValue = myDataReader(0)
    '...
End While
```

Note that trying to access any data before calling `Read` will throw an exception.